# JPA all referenced relations are retrieved (ManyToMany - ManyToOne - OneToMany)

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

Working on this 'twitter' application where a user can have posts `@OneToMany` and can have followers `@ManyToMany`.

While retrieving a user all it's posts and followers get retrieved as well.

This is all correct but it's also retrieving every 'poster' for each post (which is the user itself) and for each follower, all it's posts and followers.

I can't figure out how to limit this to the user itself.

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u"),
  @NamedQuery(
    name = "User.auth",
    query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username AND u.password = :password"
  )
})
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String username;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String password;

  @ManyToMany
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "poster", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

  @JoinTable(name = "Followers",
    joinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name = "FOLLOWER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    }
  )
  private List<User> followers = new ArrayList<>();
 .... constructor, getters and setters
```

**Post**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Post")
public class Post {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  private String content;

  @ManyToOne
  private User poster;
  .... constructor, getters and setters
```

**Outcome I get vs what I want**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "jim",
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "content": "Post 1 by jim",
            "poster": {
            // ^ this is the user itself (I don't need this one)
              "id": 1,
              "username": "jim",
              "posts": [
                // keeps recurse
              ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "followers": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "follower1",
            "posts": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "content": "Post 2 by follower 1",
                    "poster": {
                      // ^ this is the follower itself (I don't need this one)
                      "id": 2,
                      "username": "follower1",
                      "posts": [
                        // Same issue
                      ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "followers": [],    // <-- I don't need this one either
        }
    ]
}
```

Well it's pretty clear that fetching one user fill keeps fetching all it's relations which are recursive.

Is this a designer's fault or can this be ignored/limited?

Note: I am using Gson to serialise objects to JSON format

**Update**

Tried to use:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private User poster;
```

Which works but still gets the following extra prop in JSONso not sure if this is a neath solution:

```
"_persistence_poster_vh": {
                "sourceAttributeName": "poster",
                "isInstantiated": false,
                "row": {
                    "Post.ID": 3,
                    "Post.CONTENT": "Post 3 by jim",
                    "Post.DATETIME": "2018-01-22",
                    "Post.POSTER_ID": 1
                },
                "isCoordinatedWithProperty": false
            }
```

And

```
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(
    ...
  )
  private List<User> followers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Which still returns all followers (which I want!) I just don't want the followers.followers and followers.posts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess: it’s not actually fetching these objects until you try to dereference them.

Be default, JPA will eager fetch @OneToOne and @OneToMany relations, but not @ManyToOne or @ManyToMany. What happens is that when you reference these fields, it will then go and fetch the actual contents of the list.

How can you tell this is happening? Check the list’s class using `getFollowers().getClass()`
What you see won’t be a LinkedList or an ArrayList but a class from your JPA provider, probably with “Lazy” somewhere in the name. When you call Size or Get on the list, it will perform the fetch.

You can set OneToOne and OneToMany relations to be lazy as well, and use EntityGraphs to determine what entities you want to eagerly fetch as well. JPA has a number of gotchas like this.

I’ve seen GSON mentioned, and just a warning: it won’t be aware of the lazy loading lists, so you MUST tell It to avoid the properties you don’t want it to follow.

Typically with JSON marshaling, you’ll want it to ignore the parent object, so in Post, User should be ignored for example. Additionally links to same types should typically be ignored (followers) or else mapped specially, such that it doesn’t Marshall the entire object, but only produces an array of usernames. You can tell it to ignore the actual followers field, and have it marshal a getter which returns an array of usernames to implement this.

Comment: See answer on Henry

Comment: You updated your answer. You mention ignoring it in GSON and not so much the fetch itself. Well I was already thinking of this one, but isn't inefficient to fetch all the entities with all it's relations if I don't need them, and then just ignore them with a JSON converter?

Comment: Indeed it is, but in general, JPA only eagerly fetches cardinality 1 relations, not the whole list of every relation, so the overhead is a lot less than you might think. That’s also not the root of the question being asked. Basically the problem you’re having seems to be a lack of awareness of the lazy load semantics of JPA and how that interacts with things like JSON marshaling rather than a lack of appropriate lazy loading semantics on the entities.

Comment: Regarding the update to include GSON details, that wasn’t mentioned in your original question, so I hadn’t talked about it originally. When I noticed you were marshaling the entity graph, your problem became very clear.

Comment: So how is it that Ill get every User.followers.followers and User.followers.posts and keeps on being recursive?

I checked it out logging the list className and it's indeed an JPA list type. So the problem is that the converter the followers called which will get fetched on it's turn or?

Comment: GSON is walking your entity graph to generate the JSON, and as it walks the graph, the lazy lists are being loaded from the DB. It’s a little counter-intuitive, but the loads happen when GSON goes to access the contents of the fields, not when you first load the entity. That’s how lazy loading works.

Comment: Ah so it's a matter of letting GSON ignore those nested fields and they will never get fetched?

Comment: Exactly. The ideal way to handle this is to tell your Marshaller that certain fields should be marshaled in special ways. The followers field marshals not the entire User object, but just a list of usernames. It will fetch the associated users, but not their posts that way. How to do this is specific to your JSON marshaller, and TBH, I usually stick to Jackson. So, read your marshaller’s docs on how it converts field values to JSON and use its annotations to marshal the field in the way you want.

Comment: Ah yes thank you so much on finding the cause here with me. Ill check out the docs of Gson but if it's easier Ill just use Jackson!

Comment: I really doubt GSON vs Jackson is really that different. In general, you’ll want to tell the marshaller what fields to ignore using some variety of Ignore annotation and you’ll supply a type converter instead of having the marshaller walk the object graph picking out properties. This converter will convert a User to a string by taking a user object and returning the username. This converter is then specified in an annotation on the followers field. That’s pretty much all there is to it using any modern marshaller.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` in the annotation you don't want to fetch immediately. The downside is, that if you need the data later you have to access it in the scope of the still open session.

Comment: I updated my question. Using fetch=FetchType.LAZY on the Post.poster will do. But using it on User.followers will still return the followers (which I need). I just don't want the User.followers.followers and User.followers.posts.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to handle this -

1. You can either use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` anotation on attributes you want to skip while serializing the object.
2. Or you change your `FetchType` to `FetchType.LAZY` so that you can get the required data on need basis while preparing your JSON , rather than getting all records at once.

Comment: See answer on Henry

Comment: @JimVercoelen I can remove the second point point but  first point still suggest another approach to handle the case. so please feel free to edit the answer rather then downvote.